# S3 Write Access Denied - Different Policy Needed for Buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, acl

I am getting write access errors when I try to upload to a newly created S3 bucket, "dev-image", from my local dev machine.  What I found is that I can (and have been able) to upload from my app running locally to the S3 prod "image" bucket but can’t upload to "dev-image" from the same environment.  Block all public access is turned off, bucket owner can list and write objects for both buckets.  I had to specifically add a policy to the "dev-image" bucket to allow write access (PutObject).  There must be something different about the 2 buckets but I can’t see it.  Any ideas where to look?

These are the polices on AWS S3:

```
dev-image:

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1606066621241",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow all read",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dev-image/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow write from dev machine",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dev-image/*",
             }
        }
    ]
}

image:

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1445028673753",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow all read",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::image/*"
        } 
   ]
}
```

This is the form code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="s3Form" action=<%= s3FormAction %> method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <fieldset>

        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<%= imageFileName %>">
        <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="<%= S3AccessKeyId %>"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="<%= s3SuccessAction %>">
        <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="<%= encPolicy %>" >
        <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<%= signature %>" >
        <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
```

This is the code I use to encode the S3 policy:

```
public static String encodeS3Policy(String s3SuccessAction, String bucket) throws Exception
    {
        String policy =
            "{\"expiration\": \"2040-01-01T00:00:00Z\"," +
              "\"conditions\": [" +
                (bucket==null || bucket.length()==0 ? "" : "{\"bucket\": \"" + bucket + "\"}," ) +
                "[\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"\"]," +
                "{\"acl\": \"private\"}," +
                "{\"success_action_redirect\": \"" + s3SuccessAction + "\"}," +
                "[\"starts-with\", \"$Content-Type\", \"\"]," +
                "[\"content-length-range\", 0, 10485760]" +                                 // 10 MB max file up load
                "]" +
            "}";

        policy.replaceAll("\n","").replaceAll("\r","");


        // Encode the policy
        String encPolicy = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(policy.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        return encPolicy;
    }
```

Comment: Could you show your code or commands that you used?

Comment: I added the policies and some of the form code.  I'm using JSP and the post to AWS sends these fields to them, then AWS posts back status.  The thing of it is, the same code works with the image bucket and doesn't work with the dev-image bucket unless the dev-image policy explicitly states to allow object writes